# Get Jupyterhub username in spawned container

Tags: jupyterhub

I am using a Jupyterhub deployment with [DockerSpawner](https://github.com/jupyterhub/dockerspawner).
When I enter a spawned container, I have the following URL pattern:

```
https://<hostname>/user/<user-name>/lab?
```

I would like to get the value of `<user-name>` within the spawned notebook container.
Is there any possibility to either access it or forward it from Jupyterhub into the container?

Thank you,
Max

Comment: There might be a way to pass it from jupyterhub container or get it somehow, but in my recent project i got it from javascript.

Comment: You got it from Javascript within the spawned container? If so, can you share how you did it?

Comment: yes. So, as you know all the spawned container are just a simple jupyter-notebook containing all the pages ( https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/tree/master/notebook/templates ). All I did was add a script to any template or page.html to add script to all templates. And made a new image with customize template. But my purpose of getting user-name was just to show a user-name in top of header and pass it to backend server.

Answer (score 1):

Jupyterhub gives you an option to insert username through `{username}` command. If it doesn't work for you, you can try to write the next function:

```
def pre_spawn_hook(spawner):
    username = spawner.user.name
    ...
```